Troubleshoot network routing problem which disappears on safe boot
Scenario

MacMini running latest MacOS
MacBook Pro running latest MacOS
Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu 22.04
Eero Wifi Network

Observataions

MacBook Pro is able to both ping and ssh to Pi
MacMini fails with errors:

~ ping 192.168.5.77
PING 192.168.5.77 (192.168.5.77): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0

~ ssh -vvv pitosalas@192.168.5.77
OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/pitosalas/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/pitosalas/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.5.77 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/pitosalas/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/pitosalas/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: channel_clear_timeouts: clearing
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.5.77 [192.168.5.77] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: connect to address 192.168.5.77 port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host 192.168.5.77 port 22: No route to host


LanScan on Mac mini sees the IP address
tracers on Mac mini sees the IP address:

~ traceroute 192.168.5.77
traceroute to 192.168.5.77 (192.168.5.77), 64 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  192.168.5.77 (192.168.5.77)  2.777 ms  2.407 ms  2.058 ms
~


Booting MacMini in safe mode solves the problem
Turning off every startup item and then booting normal: the problem reapears



NOTE: During the first few seconds after boot up I can successfully ping and ssh and then it starts failing. Which implies that something at that point in the boot sequence causes the problem

Next Steps?

Any suggestion on how to identify what is causing the problem


The first step is to get rid of “CleanMyMac,” which, like all similar products, is worse than useless. Then uninstall the Silabs driver according to the developer’s instructions.

@LincDavis I removed both and also lots more. But still: during the first few seconds after booting up I can successfully ssh and ping the Pi. But a moment later the problem returns. Seems to point to something during the boot sequence.

Please post the output of this command: launchctl print system | sed -E '1,/services =/d; /[}]/q' | awk '!/apple|0x|edu\.|org\.|openssh|\.vix\./{print $3}'
